# How to write data in json Ionic5

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angular, ionic5

I have array items, Given below

```
    writeFile1() {
    this.testnames = [{name : "sheldon", age : "10"}, {name : "Simon", age : "11"}]

    this.file.writeFile(this.file.tempDirectory, './assets/data/demo.json', JSON.stringify(this.testnames))
};

testnames:any;
```

I need to store "testnames" to the json file which is located at "assets/ data/ demo.json". so I dont know how to do! anyone know this please helpme out.

specification:

Ionic5

Angular 10

Comment: can you add minimal reproduce steps in stackblitz.com?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `npm` package manager you can do it via `file-saver`. Just do installation of `file-saver` package :

```
npm install file-saver --save
```

Then import `file-saver` accordingly:

```
import { saveAs } from 'file-saver';

const jsonObject: any = [{name : "sheldon", age : "10"}, {name : "Simon", age : "11"}];

const blob = new Blob([JSON.stringify(jsonObject)], {type : 'application/json'});
saveAs(blob, 'demo.json');
```

Keep in mind that web browser doesnt have the permission to write content to specified location. Instead what you can do is that you can create the File object in the browser iteself and download it accordingly. If it is a web browser it will be downloaded to your default downloading location. I'm providing a Angular based solution here since you have mentioned angular in your question.